# Python Pandas Box Plot Ordering the X Axis - Months

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

[image: Picture of Chart]

The order of my months on the X-axis are weird. It is starting with December - January. I would like to to start with January - December

I believe it might be something to do with the index, I am not for sure.

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename,parse_dates=["Date"], index_col = "Date")
data.reset_index(inplace=True)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (20,7), dpi = 80)
sns.boxplot(x='month', y='', data = data.loc[~data.year.isin([2005,2019]),:])
axes[1].set_title('Combined Attrition Month-wise Box Plot\n(The Seasonality)', fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

I expect it to be January - December

Comment: You could replace `x='month'` with `data['Date'].dt.month`, which gives you `1,2,...,12` on the `x-axis`, and rename the ax title later.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it!